# Unable to locate an element because of timeout in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to finding a way to check if a new page/window is opened successfully and has content or not. I know that selenium is not able to check code 200 to see if the page is successfully loaded or not. So what should I do in order to find out if the page is loaded successfully?

```
while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#showbtn").click()
            print ("Page Loaded Successfully")
            break
        except:
            print ("Page loading failed")
            time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for the presence of an element, you can use [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html?highlight=webdriverwait#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait.until) with [`presence_of_element_located`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html?highlight=presence#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ...))
)
```

That will wait until the element is either found or the wait time is reached (10 seconds in the example)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but sometimes my new page loading failed. and I need to reload the page.

Comment: You can use the answer to check if the page loaded successfully or not as if your element isn't present (assuming it always should be), then the page isn't finished loading or failed.

Answer (score 0):

To Click on button Induce `WebDriverWait()` and `element_to_be_clickable()` and then click on button.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#showbtn"))).click()
```

OR to check pageload successfully you can induce javascript executor before interacting the the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda drv: drv.execute_script('return document.readyState == "complete"'))
```

You need to add following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

**Updated code:**

```
while True:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda drv: drv.execute_script('return document.readyState == "complete"'))
            print("Page Loaded Successfully")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#showbtn"))).click()                     
            break
        except:
            print ("Page loading failed")
            driver.refresh()
```

Comment: What to do if page load failed ?

Comment: You can reload the page using driver.refresh()

Comment: @Mahdi : Updated code.Try this out and let me know how this goes.